# pandas DataFrame.query expression that returns all rows by default

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have discovered the pandas DataFrame.query method and it *almost* does exactly what I needed it to (and implemented my own parser for, since I hadn't realized it existed but really I should be using the standard method).

I would like my users to be able to specify the query in a configuration file. The syntax seems intuitive enough that I can expect my non-programmer (but engineer) users to figure it out.

There's just one thing missing: a way to select everything in the dataframe. Sometimes what my users want to use is every row, so they would put 'All' or something into that configuration option. In fact, that will be the default option.

I tried df.query('True') but that raised a KeyError. I tried df.query('1') but that returned the row with index 1. The empty string raised a ValueError.

The only things I can think of are 1) put an if clause every time I need to do this type of query (probably 3 or 4 times in the code) or 2) subclass DataFrame and either reimplement query, or add a query_with_all method:

```
import pandas as pd

class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def query_with_all(self, query_string):
        if query_string.lower() == 'all':
            return self
        else:
            return self.query(query_string)
```

And then use my own class every time instead of the pandas one. Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: If the users knows the column names upfront, he could `df.query('a == a')` where `a` is one of the columns, but doesn't seem clean. Ah, may not work for rows with `null`

Comment: Or, have a global `all_true = [True]*len(df)` and then refer it `df.query('@all_true ')` perhaps? Or, have a all True reserved column if that isn't a constraint and refer `df.query('_all_true_col')`?

Comment: Zero, the columns will change, but there is one column that is absolutely required to be there and not be Null, so I will keep that in mind as an option. I don't think I would make my users put that in the config file, but rather would replace 'all' with that for internal use. But still not as clean as I would like, as you mention..

Comment: Zero, as to your second suggestion, I would need to use the same query on different dataframes of different lengths, without knowing the length ahead of time.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the third suggestion. Possibility too, but of course with large dataframes would worsen my potential memory issues.

Comment: all_true = 'index == index' works

Comment: Yep `'index == index'` will work, but fails if it has `nan` in index, but very rare perhaps.

Comment: @moink: I have the same problem, did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @Thomas, I ended up implementing my own module with something quite similar to the code I showed, though I didn't end up using inheritance, and several other functions on queries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep things simple, and use a function:

```
def query_with_all(data_frame, query_string):
    if query_string == "all":
        return data_frame
    return data_frame.query(query_string)
```

Whenever you need to use this type of query, just call the function with the data frame and the query string. There's no need to use any extra `if` statements or subclass `pd.Dataframe`.

---

If you're restricted to using `df.query`, you can use a global variable

```
ALL = slice(None)
df.query('@ALL', engine='python')
```

If you're not allowed to use global variables, and if your DataFrame isn't MultiIndexed, you can use

```
df.query('tuple()')
```

All of these will property handle `NaN` values.

Comment: Well, this is an obvious choice (and also in the OP), but the idea would be to keep this inside query if at all possible?

Comment: @coldspeed Sorry for not reading your post / the comments thoroughly. I've added two solutions that stay (mostly) inside the query.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried both, and both throw errors. Did you use any options with `query`? The first one gives "ValueError: unknown type object" and the second one "TypeError: unsupported expression type: <class 'tuple'>". Any idea?

Comment: What versions are running? I have pd.__version__ = '0.23.4', np.__version__ = '1.15.4', sys.version='3.7.1 (default, Oct 23 2018, 14:07:42) \n[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]'.

Comment: Same versions, no difference. I think these will work if you add engine='python' as an argument. Your second option will not work on MultiIndexed dataframes.

Comment: Anyway, this is good enough for me, and covers *most* use cases. Good answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for `pandas==1.1.4` with exactly the errors that @cs95 described

Comment: In some applications you would have to write a code generator becuase the combinatorial complexity gets high. That would take longer to code (cost more money) than a simple expression that can be put into the query() part which simply returns all rows.

Answer (score 3):

`df.query('ilevel_0 in ilevel_0')` will always return the full dataframe, also when the index contains `NaN` values or even when the dataframe is completely empty.

In you particular case you could then define a global variable `all_true = 'ilevel_0 in ilevel_0'` (as suggested in the comments by [Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137255/zero)) so that your engineers could use the name of the global variable in their config file instead.

This statement is just a dirty way to properly query `True` like you already tried. `ilevel_0` is a more formal way of making sure you are referring the index. See the docs here for more details on using `in` and `ilevel_0`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method

Comment: This is the correct answer! It works great. They chose the wrong "correct answer" because in some applications we are not able to simply write different codes which includes or excludes the query function, unless we also write a code generator, which is a whole lot of more dev time. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the simplest way to get the complete dataframe from the query:

```
df.query("index==index")
```